# is it possible to notify all users using Laravel notification with pusher?

Tags: laravel, notifications, pusher

Is it possible to create/send notification(s) to all users when there is new announcement.

I want all users to be notified using the database notification.

Since most of the tutorials I have seen are all email notification, is this possible? Please attach links or any idea on how I could implement this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Literally in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications#sending-notifications):

> Alternatively, you may send notifications via the Notification facade.
>   **This is useful primarily when you need to send a notification to
>   multiple notifiable entities such as a collection of users**. To send
>   notifications using the facade, pass all of the notifiable entities
>   and the notification instance to the send method:
>
> ```
> Notification::send($users, new InvoicePaid($invoice));
> ```

So yes, you can send to all user by getting them from the database and sending a notification using the facade.

For example:

```
Notification::send(User::all(), new InvoicePaid($invoice));
```

Comment: sir the code that you have provide where to add those? inside notification model?

Comment: no, lets say you need to inform user that your are register, so use this code under you register method of RegisterController before line `return $user`